# One service/resource class for all entities not working jpa rest

Tags: java, rest, jpa-2.0

I am trying to make a generic web service class which will get me the entity object as provided in the url.I have mentioned all the classes below.The problem that I am facing is when I am calling  getDataById method through get Method ,I get output as {} only.I am unable to get all the fields in the json object that the get method is returning.

**BaseEntity Class:-**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BaseEntity {
    public BaseEntity() {
        super();
    }
}
```

**Employees Class:-**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employees")
@Entity
public class Employees extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2506140104403524623L;
    @Column(name = "COMMISSION_PCT")
    private Integer commissionPct;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @Id
    private Integer employeeId;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "hire_date")
    private Date hireDate;
    @Column(name = "job_id")
    private String jobId;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Integer salary;
    @Column(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private Integer managerId;
    /*@Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Integer departmentId;*/

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Departments dept;


    public Employees() {
    }
    public Employees(int commissionPct,String email,int employeeId,StringfirstName,Date hireDate,String jobId,
                     String lastName,String phoneNumber,int salary,int managerId,int department_id){
        this.commissionPct=commissionPct;
        this.email=email;
        this.employeeId=employeeId;
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.hireDate=hireDate;
        this.jobId=jobId;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
        this.salary=salary;
        this.managerId=managerId;
        //this.departmentId=departmentId;
    }

    @XmlElement    
    public Integer getCommissionPct() {
        return commissionPct;
    }

    public void setCommissionPct(Integer commissionPct) {
        this.commissionPct = commissionPct;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getHireDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
        return df.format(hireDate);
    }

    public void setHireDate(String hireDate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
        Date hireDt = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(hireDate).getTime());
        this.hireDate = hireDt;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }

    public void setJobId(String jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getmanagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    public void setmanagerId(Integer salary) {
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }
    /*
    @XmlElement
    public Integer getdepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setdepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }*/
    public Departments getDepartments(){
        return this.dept;
    }

}
```

**Departments Class:-**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Departments")
@Entity
public class Departments extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1246294097529286468L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Integer departmentId;
    @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    @Column(name = "LOCATION_ID")
    private Integer locationId;
    @Column(name = "MANAGER_ID")
    private Integer managerId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dept",cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private List<Employees> empList;

    public Departments(){

    }

    public Departments(int departmentId,String departmentName,int locationId,int managerId){
        this.departmentId=departmentId;
        this.departmentName=departmentName;
        this.locationId=locationId;
        this.managerId=managerId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Integer getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public Integer getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public Integer getManagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    public void setManagerId(Integer managerId) {
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }

    public List<Employees> getEmployees(){
        return this.empList;
    }
}
```

**Service Class:-**

```
@Path("/{Entity}")
public class EntityBOImpl {

    private Class entity;
    private EntityManager em;
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private  void getEntityDao(String en) throws ClassNotFoundException, NamingException {
        entity=Class.forName("oal.test.entity."+en);
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Project1");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public BaseEntity getDataById(@PathParam("Entity") String ent,@PathParam("id") Integer pk) throws ClassNotFoundException, NamingException {
        getEntityDao(ent);
        return (BaseEntity)em.find(entity,pk);
    }
}
```